# Evaluate $\lim_{\mu \to \infty} \int_{\frac{\mu}{2}}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(t-\mu)^2}{2}}dt$

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, limits, improper-integrals

As in the title, the problem is to evaluate the integral
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\mu\to\infty}\int_{\frac{\mu}{2}}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(t-\mu)^2}{2}}dt. \label{integral}
\end{equation}

If one examines this graphically, then it appears that the integral should equate to 1 (see picture below). 
[image]
An accompanying intuitive argument is to note that the integrand is the density function of an $N(\mu,1)$ random variable, and at the limit, the distance between $\mu$ and $\mu/2$ approaches $\infty$. Since standard deviation is fixed, we should approach the situation where the area of the tail left of $\mu/2$ goes to zero, and hence the integral goes to 1.

However, when one examines the integral analytically, it's quite odd since a (naive) interpretation of the limit suggests that we are evaluating an improper integral of the form $\int_{\infty}^\infty \dots dt$, which I have not seen before.

Therefore:

1) Does this integral actually equal 1?

2) Can this be shown from the given expression?

Comment: The area left of the maximum will not go to zero.  It's always $1/2$.

Comment: But we are not evaluating the integral from the left of the maximum, but rather, half of the left of the maximum $\mu/2$.

Comment: Ah, I see, okay.

Comment: You might be helped with some approximations of the error functions, see for example here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Approximation_with_elementary_functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ is normal with mean $0$ and variance $1$ then the integral equals $P\{X+\mu >\mu /2\}=P\{X >-\mu /2\} \to 1$ as $\mu \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

My own solution based from Paul's suggestion of examining the error function:

Write the cumulative distribution of a $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ random variable as

\begin{align}
\Phi\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right) &= \frac{1}{2}\left[1 + \text{erf}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{2}}\right)\right].
\end{align}Then the integral becomes
\begin{align}
1 - \Phi\left(\frac{\mu}{2}\right) &= 1 - \frac{1}{2}\left(1 + \text{erf}\left(\frac{\mu/2 - \mu}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)\\
&= 1 - \frac{1}{2}\left(1 + \text{erf}\left(-\frac{\mu}{2\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)\\
&= 1 - \frac{1}{2}\left(1 - \text{erf}\left(\frac{\mu}{2\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)\\
&\to 1 - \frac{1}{2}\left(1 - 1\right),\\
&= 1,
\end{align}
as $\mu \to \infty$.